# How to $count and $group within MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to count the `status` and `group` them by country.

Data:

```
[
    { id: 100, status: 'ordered', country: 'US', items: [] },
    { id: 101, status: 'ordered', country: 'UK', items: [] },
    { id: 102, status: 'shipped', country: 'UK', items: [] },
]
```

Desired aggregation outcome:

```
[
    { _id: 'US', status: { ordered: 1} },
    { _id: 'UK', status: { ordered: 1, shipped: 1 } }
]
```

I can `$count` and `$group`, but I am not sure how to put this together. Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks,
bluepuama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `country` and `status`, and count total
- `$group` by only `country` and construct array of `status` and count in key-value format
- `$set` to update `status` field to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { country: "$country", status: "$status" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.country",
      status: { $push: { k: "$_id.status", v: "$count" } }
    }
  },
  { $set: { status: { $arrayToObject: "$status" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UXq8FyUZhuY)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single `$group` stage like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country",
      "shipped": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$status",
                "ordered"
              ]
            },
            0,
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      "ordered": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$status",
                "shipped"
              ]
            },
            0,
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      status: {
        shipped: "$shipped",
        ordered: "$ordered"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-0T2kA0dGL)